# TSQL copy one database to another

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, t-sql

I have two identical databases lets call them A & B, what I want to do is to have two copy options:

1- Copy the whole database and overwrite everything from A to B with TSQL

2- With TSQL I want to loop over each table row in A and check the last modified date filed if is greater then last modified date in B table row copy and overwrite the whole row.

Please let me now if something is not clear, any help is very appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this? If database A is always going to win why not just setup replication or backup/restore on a scheduled basis to keep database B current?

Comment: If you have a copy of visual studio 2010 Premium, you can do a database compare on them.  You can then generate scripts to bring the other database up to date.  You can pick and choose what's included in the script.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to copy an entire database.  Not just a table?

Comment: the purpose is that A database is the beta and B is the live database so it is going to execute the update from site administration with C# not in Visual Studio, yes my number 1 is to copy an entire database, but number 2 will check on each row if date modified in A > B then will copy just that row. thanks.

Comment: I do have visual studio 2010 Premium, so do you think if I do that generate scripts then put that scrit in stored procedure to run the same update from code?

Comment: DO not even consider looping through rows unless you want your server tuied up for hours.

Comment: Actually, the script will change as schema/data changes - so you won't be able to simply put it into a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio 2010 Premium or Ultimate you can do a schema compare and create the new database on the server you need to.  Getting the data over there is another matter entirely and is something you can perform with SSIS or linked server queries, especially considering you're simply pumping data from one side to another.

See this post for schema compare tools:
[How can I find the differences between two databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8987856/387041)

Something we've recently complete is using the CHECKSUM and Table Switching to bring in new data, keep the old and compare both sets.

You would basically set up three tables for each doing the switch, one for production, one for   _staging and one that's an _old table that's an exact schema match.  Three tables are needed since when you perform the switch (which is instantaneous, you need to switch into an empty table).  You would pump the data into the staging table and execute a switch to change the pointer for the table definition from production to _old and from _staging to production.  AND if you have the checksum calculated on each row, you can company and see what's new or different.

It's worked out well with our use of it, but it's a fair amount of prep work to make it happen, which could be prohibitive depending on your environment.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191160.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx

Here's a sample query that we ran on GoDaddy.com's sql web editor:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable (Val1 INT NOT NULL)
CREATE TABLE TestTable2 (Val1 INT NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO TestTable (Val1) VALUES (4) 

SELECT * FROM TestTable 

ALTER TABLE TestTable SWITCH TO TestTable2 

SELECT * FROM TestTable2
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer and explanations, so do you  think this concept may not work in shared host environments, like in godaddy.com or 1and1.com?

Comment: I don't believe the table switching functionality is version dependent, but my colleague tried the command on his GoDaddy.com web edition of SQL and it worked for him.

Comment: question, what is (Val1) and VALUES (4) stand for? is Val1 column name you mean?

Comment: Correct.  In the insert statement, you can specify what column and values you want to insert.  Everything above the `SELECT` statement is just prep for the switch (inserting data).  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx

Comment: Hey Vinnie, I tried to run this script:

ALTER TABLE liveDB.dbo.cms_tblContent SWITCH TO betaDB.dbo.cms_tblContent 

SELECT * FROM liveDB.dbo.cms_tblContent 


but I am getting an error that cant do it because each table is in different database, I thought that was the whole point of this script to move from one DB to another?

Comment: It won't move tables across databases.  The whole point of the table switch was to allow you to retain the data you already had and compare it to the most recent version of that table.  The ALTER will only switch in the same database in the same schema.  You will still have to create a process to copy the data from one DB to another.  Part of your question involved comparing the old to the new and this is the way to do it all in one database.